# Ubuntu 20.04 flickring when using Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop [Omen 15 2020].

I use an external monitor.

When I placed the usb-stick with Ubuntu, I tried it out and everything worked Ok!

Upon finishing the installation I enrolled in MOK.

When I first started the computer, only the laptop monitor was detected. I checked and the used driver was the X.org driver. Afterwards, I changed to Nvidia 470  [My laptop has a NVIDIA GTX 1650 Ti]. When I rebooted the laptop I had the second monitor working but the laptop was like this:

[laptop monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms2wM.jpg)

I am not able to use the laptop monitor.. I was able to circumvent the situation by making the external monitor a single display.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `nvidia-settings` app. It is an app created by `nvidia` themselves, which reads in input from your system, takes additional input from the user in the form of preferences, and uses the data collected to  performs automatic configuration and adjustment of your setup. It almost always leaves your system in a state that lets you enjoy it without constantly having to tune and reconfigure it (which is usually the case when trying to manage multi-display Nvidia / Xorg (pre-Wayland) setups with `xrandr`.)

For installation and (some) usage instructions, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373649/ubuntu-20-04-keyboard-and-main-display-disabled-after-connecting-2nd-monitor/1373659#1373659).

Comment: I have the app. It comes with Ubuntu... However, I do not know what to change to make the screen work correctly

Comment: Not with 20.04, it doesn't. I have 20.04, and I specifically remember having to download via apt. I even checked my logs to make sure. The nvidia drivers themselves don't even come with Ubuntu. Can you post a pic of the nvidia-settings window.. specifically, the tab that shows your monitors (it looks like the 'displays' tab ui in the Ubuntu Desktop settings menu). Ill look at the interface for a refresher, its been awhile..

Comment: Hi, this? https://i.ibb.co/pJFtRg1/2022-01-25-09-22.png

Comment: Yea. Your config is off. Updating answer. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Sry, something came up yest, and I had to stop suddenly... Do you have `nvidia-prime` apt pkg installed? Also, how many monitors were enabled when you took the linked screenshot? Finally, when you run `lsmod ` and grep nvidia from output, what do you see? Should find module `nvidia-fb` and oits reverse deps.

Comment: Hi, when I run `lsmod | grep nvidia` I get: `nvidia_uvm           1036288  0
nvidia_drm             61440  12
nvidia_modeset       1200128  14 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35315712  674 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        253952  2 amdgpu,nvidia_drm
drm                   557056  18 gpu_sched,drm_kms_helper,nvidia,amdgpu,drm_ttm_helper,nvidia_drm,ttm`

I have the `nvidia-prime ` installed

Comment: I had one monitor on. The built-in monitor of the laptop is constantly flickering which is not good. So I am running on an external monitor.

Comment: One thing that jumps out : You don't currently use `nvidia-fb` module, which is used on my system as the provider for `xrandr`. However, it was auto-configured by `nvidia-settings`, so I am not sure about configuring it manually. I will check out my `xorgs.conf` and see what I can come up with. What I would recommend for you is to first (with `nvidia-settings` gui window loaded on good monitor) run the command `xrandr --auto` to get both running (even if flicker persists) just long enough to click the configure button in the `nvidia-settings` window.

Comment: It probably needs both to be enabled when it does its thing, so that it knows this is the preferred config.